# How do you synchronize android clients with a python server?

Tags: android, python, server, client, synchronize

I have a python server and about 10 android clients, using sockets. It is really important that when the server sends a message, all clients receive it at the same time (say 1/10th of a second of difference).

But the connection is over Wifi, and some devices get the message later than others, which gives a very messy result. I don't want to get the latency of every device because this is a very unreliable approach. I want something as accurate as possible.

For example, in FPS games, it is common to have a countdown at the start of the round, and every player can start playing at the same time. What kind of logic lies behind this?

As for what my code currently looks like:

I use a BufferedReader in android to read every line sent by the server. The server is a console application in which you can type a message, and when you press enter, every listed client receives it with a new thread for every client.

java method receiving messages:

```
private void readMessage() throws IOException {
    String data;

    while ((data = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        data = data.toUpperCase();
        if (data.startsWith("POSITION")) {
            String[] splitData = data.split("/");
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, splitData[1]);
            mMainActivity.setDevicePosition(Integer.parseInt(splitData[1]));
        } else {
            String message = data.substring(data.indexOf('/') + 1, data.length());
            int devices = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(0, data.indexOf('/')));
            if (message.length() >= devices) {
                message += " ";
            } else {
                int difference = devices - message.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
                    message += " ";
                }
            }
            mMainActivity.printMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

python line :

```
for cl in clients_list:
        start_new_thread(send_message_thread, (cl, message,))
```

Comment: I assume you're making a game. Things don't actually happen at the exact same time on every client. How that's handled varies from game type to game type. In FPS games, you normally have a dedicated server that has the "truth" on it. All of the clients send commands to that server, the server runs the commands, updates the game world, and sends out the new game world to all the clients for them to render. The client also predicts what will happen in the next .1 second so it has something to render while waiting for new packets.

Comment: In an RTS game, each client sends every other client a batch of commands every ~200 milliseconds or so. Every client receives packets from every other client, then updates. If any packet is missing, the game pauses and normally displays a message saying that someone (whoever's packet hasn't arrived) is lagging. If it's a 3 player game and only A is missing B's packet, then B and C won't immediately know - they'll run for another 200 ms. They'll discover it because A won't send a new packet of commands to them - it'll send that it's missing B's packet, instead.